# When using Doxygen for C++ sources a size of font for \subsubsection is larger than for \section and \subsection

Tags: c++, formatting, doxygen

I installed Doxygen 1.6.1.

I used `\section`, `\subsection` and `\subsubsection` for titles in C++ sources.

I surprisingly obtained titles in which \subsubsection have large font size than for \subsection and \section.

How can this be fixed?
CSS should be used to workaround this or can I fix my doxygen installation to obtain expected common behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Doxygen does not specify size of font in css template for `\subsubsection`, style for h4-tag should be specified. CSS should be overridden.