# How to change fontsize of \section, \subsection etc. in Doxygen?

Tags: css, formatting, doxygen

I want to change the \section and \subsection font size of doxygen's html-output. In addition, I would like to add numbers to the sections and (sub-)subsections in the style:

1 Section1

1.1 Subsection1.1

1.1.1 Subsubsection

From the manual I found out that I should copy the customdoxygen.css and change it to represent my needs. Unfortunately I don't know anything about css and could not manage to find the command that is responsible for the font size of \section and \subsection.

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2608403/when-using-doxygen-for-c-sources-a-size-of-font-for-subsubsection-is-larger-t), it is said that one should define a h4-tag. Is that correct? And how could I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what you do:
In the configuration doxyfile:

```
HTML_EXTRA_STYLESHEET = mystylesheet.css
```

Settings in this stylesheet override the settings in other stylesheets.
Then create the text file mystylesheet.css.

To change the font size add to mystylesheet.css a style for h1. For example:

```
h1 { font-size:1.5em; }
```

To handle numbered headings, you use styles with CSS counters. Here's an example:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
body {counter-reset: h2}
h2 {counter-reset: h3}
h3 {counter-reset: h4}
h4 {counter-reset: h5}
h5 {counter-reset: h6}

h2:before {counter-increment: h2; content: counter(h2) ". "}
h3:before {counter-increment: h3; content: counter(h2) "." counter(h3) ". "}
h4:before {counter-increment: h4; content: counter(h2) "." counter(h3) "." counter(h4) ". "}
h5:before {counter-increment: h5; content: counter(h2) "." counter(h3) "." counter(h4) "." counter(h5) ". "}
h6:before {counter-increment: h6; content: counter(h2) "." counter(h3) "." counter(h4) "." counter(h5) "
</style>
</head>  
<body>
<h1> Demonstration of Numbered Headings</h1>
<p>To create numbered headings, you can use CSS counters. For details search for "CSS counters".</p>
<p>In this example the numbered headings begin from heading level 2. Heading level 1 is reserved for the page title. </p>
<h2>Setting Up the Style</h2>
The css style properties specify when to reset the heading level counter, and when to increment it. 
<h3>Creating the Counter</h3>
<p>You can create a named counter with the counter-reset property.  The value of counter-reset is the name of the counter. For details search for "CSS counter-reset".</p>
<h3>When Does the Value Reset</h3>
<p>It resets when the tag appears of which the counter-reset is a property.</p>
<h2>Displaying the Counters</h2>
<p>The counters are displayed by specifying a before selector for the heading levels, and styling it with content that includes counters for the heading levels preceding the current level, as well as the current level.</p>
<h3>Where is the Example?</h3>
<p>In the style tag of this page.</p>
<h4>I Can't See It</h4>
<p>Use the source, Luke.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks a lot Neale! Is there a chance to get the counters in the index and toc as well?